# How to encrypt a code object in python for both windows and linux

Tags: python, linux, segmentation-fault, termux

How to Encrypt a code object to base64, bytes, sha256 etc any of them but that must support both of windows and Linux/Termux. I have tried `marshal.dumps` but it only work on that os where it was made. Like: I converted that code object to bytes with `marshal.dumps` on windows. But it only runs on windows, when I move that code to termux/linux, it shows `Segmentation Fault`. And if I convert to bytes with the same method on linux/termux, and then move that converted code to windows, it shows a dialog box and says `python is not responding`. The main code is on [github](https://github.com/dev-zarir/pyenc). Here is a sample code:

```
my_code="print('This is encrypted code')"
enc_code=compile(my_code, 'string', 'exec')
# i want to encrypt this enc_code that supports both windows and linux
```

### Edit:

There should be a decrypt method. I also want to decrypt that code object and execute that with exec function.
Eg:

```
code=compile('print("Sometext")', 'nothing', 'exec')
code.encrypted_value='iurefbiuyrencuigfbc8yoiwusenowrov'
```

And decrypt that encrypted value then execute it:

```
exec('iurefbiuyrencuigfbc8yoiwusenowrov'.decrypted_code_object)
```

Comment: What is your actual end goal? You've mentioned base64 and bytes, neither of which is cryptographic in any sense, and sha256, which is a one-way hash, not an encryption algorithm. What are you trying to accomplish here? This may also be an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/248627).

Comment: I just want to encrypt the code object.

Answer (score 0):

You can use cryptography library, havent checked it but I think it is compatible with both linux and windows.

```
from cryptography.fernet import Fernet
my_code="print('This is encrypted code')"

key=Fernet.generate_key()
print (key) #SAVE THIS KEY this key will be used to decrypt

## Encryption
f=Fernet(key)
encrypted_text=f.encrypt(my_code.encode()) #encrypting your code
print (encrypted_text)


### Decryption
f=Fernet(key) #passing the key you saved
decrypted_text=f.decrypt(encrypted_text) #decrypting the code
print(decrypted_text)
```

Comment: Hashing is not encrypting. By design, hashes are not reversible. You cannot go from the hash back to the plaintext.

Comment: how to unhash this? I also want to decrypt this value and execute with exec function

Comment: Hashing is not encrypting. You cannot decrypt sha256 it is a one way hash function. Means you cannot get the text back.

Comment: @ibadia Ok, is there any encrypting system? View this edited question

Comment: There is a cryptography library which can do the task. Check my edited latest answer.

Comment: Thanks, but your code indicates to string encryption. I want to encrypt code object. Eg: `my_code=compile('print("SECRET CODE")', 'string', 'exec')`